# Java Stax how to get only value of specific child nodes

Tags: java, xml, stax

I use Stax for get nodeName and nodeValue of my xml file (size 90 MB) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name1>
    <type>
        <coord>67</coord>
        <umc>57657</umc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>989</eng>
        <spa>123</spa>
    </lang>
</name1>
<name2>
    <type>
        <coord>534</coord>
        <umc>654654</umc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>354</eng>
        <spa>2424</spa>
    </lang>
</name2>
<name3>
    <type>
        <coord>23432</coord>
        <umc>14324</umc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>141</eng>
        <spa>142</spa>
    </lang>
</name3>
```

I can get localName but not child nodes... if I want to get the value for all child nodes different of `'spa'` how can I process to get that ?

Java:

```java
XMLStreamReader dataXML = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(path));
while (dataXML.hasNext())
{
    int type = dataXML.next();
    switch(type)
    {
        case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
             System.out.println(dataXML.getLocalName());
             break;

        case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
             System.out.println(dataXML.getText());
             break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's linked to Your problem, but in an example XML You provided `<lang>` end tag is wrong. It should be `</lang>`

Comment: @zolv It's not linked to my problem but thank you ! I just edited

Comment: I've just checked Your code and in logs I can clearly see every logged tag - exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of element being parsed it's needed to introduce variable holding the current tag name as well as the variable with the tag name(s) of interest:

```
   String localname = null;
   String tagName = "spa";

    while (dataXML.hasNext()) {
        int type = dataXML.next();
        switch (type) {

            case XMLStreamReader.SPACE:
                continue;

            case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                localname = dataXML.getLocalName();
                System.out.println(dataXML.getLocalName());
                break;

            case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS:
                if (!tagName.equals(localname)) {
                    System.out.println(dataXML.getText());
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

In case there are several tags you want to handle, variable tagName could be replaced with a list:

```
List<String> tagNames = new ArrayList<>();
tagNames.add("spa");
```

And the check would be following:

```
if (!tagNames.contains(localname)) {
    System.out.println(dataXML.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use StAX parsing. It means You pull events from a parser. StAX parsing doesn't have any information about detail structure of Your document.
Please check [Differences between DOM, SAX or StAX](http://blog.yamanyar.com/2009/04/differences-between-dom-sax-or-stax.html) and [Java StAX parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_stax_parser.htm)

If You want to get children of Your XML element, You need to track it by Yourself.

If You really want children being accessed in a convenient way - use DOM parsing strategy. But as You've mentioned, Your document is ~90MB what may be really heavy to load it fully.